# Shiny action button that can conditionally fetch data or run calculations (or do Both)

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I have a unique situation that I was wondering if anyone could help brainstorm.

My Shiny app has a selection of dropdowns, where users can select dates, names etc. 
Followed by three action buttons: Import, Run, and Reset. Generally, they should be clicked in order, Import > Run. But sometimes, user can just click Run, and it should have same functionality as Import and Run.

Import Button > fetches data from database and renders in data-table output.
Run Button > Must run calculations on the data-table that Import rendered, and render new tables to be output elsewhere in application. However, If user, forgets to fetch data from database, then Run button must fetch the data, and then output that table. Then run calcs, and render the new table elsewhere as well.
Reset Button > Just clears the data table that Import created.

I am having trouble getting the Run button to Import & Run calculations (if user forgets to click Import first. Can this be done?

Right now, I am noticing that if I click "Import" it automatically triggers a "Run" event.

**Server.R**

```
`rv <- reactiveValue()`

`data <- eventReactive(input$import, {
 // fetch data 
 // returns data.frame
})

`observe({ //database import event
rv[["dbdata"]] <- data()
})`

`getHoldings <-function(){
return(click("import"))
}`

`observeEvent(input$run, {
if (is.null(rv["dbdata"]){
   getHoldings(); 
} 
})`

`calcs <- eventReactive({input$run, input$stocks
 },{
 // uses input$stocks.
  port <- rhandsontable:: hot_to_r(input$stocks) %>%
  dplyr:: ....
  port$id....
  return(....)
})`

`observeEvent(input$reset, {
 rv[['dbdata']] <- data.frame(...)
  })

`output$stocks <- rhandsontable:: renderRHandsontable({
 DF <- rv[['dbdata']]
 rhandsontable:: hot_cols(....)
 })`

`output$summary <- DT::renderDataTable.... {DT::datable({
  uses calcs() ...      
  })`
```

**UI.R**

```
  `Shiny:: sidePanel()
  selectinput()
  dateinput() ... // other dropdowns etc

  rhandsontable::rHandsontableOutput("stocks")
  ...
  shiny::mainPanel

  DT:dataTableOutput('summary')`
```

Answer (score 0):

It's diffuclt to be sure eactly what you want as you haven't given us a simple self-contained example.  But if I understand you correctly, I think you can get what you want by creating standalone finctions to import (`importData()`, say) and do the calculations (`doCalculations()`, say.  Each sets a flag to indicate that it's been run.  Then call the standalone functions in each `observeEvent`:

```
observeEvent(input$import, {
  importData()
})

observeEvent(input$run, {
  if (!importFlag) importData()
  doCalculations()
})
```

Don't forget to reset your flags in the `input$reset` handler.

Depending on your situation, you may even be able to make your standalone functions reactives themselves.  That would take care of the flag handling automatically:

```
importedData <- reactive({
  req(input$import, input$run)
  <your code here>
})

calculatedData <- reactive({
  req(input$run)
  <your code here, referencing importedData()>
})

summaryData <- reactive({
  <your code here, referencing calculatedData()
})

output$summary <- DT::...({
  <something referencing summaryData()>
})
```

And so on.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've added updated server and UI files that may provide more context in what my current implementation is. If you get a chance please take a look.

Comment: slight change is that I'm using uses input$stocks, to run calcs eventReactive, then calcs(), is used by output$summary.